# A PI gave me 2 days to accept his offer after I mentioned I still have another interview. Is this normal?

Tags: postdocs, job-search, job, interview

Last week, I had a postdoc interview for a "senior" role. They call it senior because they've asked me to lead on a (perhaps the) research problem. For the interview, they asked me to prepare a 10 minutes presentation where I propose a research plan. My presentation focused on a particular case with a detailed plan. I proposed to work on a particular case simply because it's all I can do at the moment (in terms of my current knowledge and research experience from my Ph.D.).

They complimented my presentation and the fact that I have a clear plan. But they did say that they want someone to work on the research problem from a general perspective and then perhaps at the end, target a particular case. The researcher is also expected to show *leadership* during his research when working on the project. The issue is the general case will require a lot of reading. The interview was really good and I have answered all of their questions. But they didn't ask much to be honest (I guess it's because my presentation was technical and focused on the particular case and not the whole problem). But I wasn't expecting an offer because our research goals weren't the same.

Now that I gave some background to why I am hesitant, I will get to my question. The PI sent me an informal email just two days after the interview, saying that I did a good interview and I should expect good news. The next day, he did say that he's going to offer me the position (again informally) and that I need to accept so he can send a formal letter. I told him that I am interested but I have another interview next week in which I've **confirmed** my attendance. I said that we can start the formal procedure next week after my next interview. He basically said that you have 2 days (before my next interview) to accept otherwise he will move to the waiting list. It's my first time receiving an offer, is this normal? To give 2 days as a deadline knowing that I asked for more time for my second interview? Note that a 5 day-deadline is more than enough to have an idea about both postdoc positions!

**Update**

I want to thank you for answers. Really good points were mentioned that help see things from both sides (candidate's and the PI's point view). For this particular case, I decided to quickly decline the PI's offer informally.

Comment: It's a red flag that's on fire being towed by a red plane that is also on fire and is currently plummeting towards the earth, where it will leave a smoking red crater.

Comment: @Libor, colorful. Possibly correct.

Comment: If you accept informally (nothing written) you can still reject formally. If they send out rejections to the other candidates upon your merely informal "acceptance", it's their loss if you have second thoughts; and they can still inquire with a rejected candidate if they are still interested in the position anyway.

Comment: This might be region-dependent. Where are you applying?

Comment: @Libor still though an accurate description of the hiring process of academia in the country I am in. People say they want things done yesterday, because it needed to be done yesterday (not like in industry where this is a hyperbole)

Comment: @user151413 It's really is _very_ country/region dependent. From my (EU) perspective, having to make a decision before even seeing the formal offer feels completely backwards. Yet there are countries where a "formal offer" is pretty much the last step in a hiring process.

Comment: @TooTea No kidding? (Or: What do you call a formal offer?) E.g. in Germany the contract is often only signed on the first work day. Then again, the offer and acceptance is considered formal, and you would leave a very bad aftertaste if you cancelled after offering/accepting without good reason. (Of course, this were no much different with a contract: No-one wants a postdoc who is unwilling to do the job, and during the initial few weeks/months, it is realtively easy to terminate the contract on short notice.)

Comment: Run away! Run away!!!

Comment: This is how the PI would treat you if you agree to work him. If you're OK with that--- and the fact that you made this post at least suggests that you aren't--- fine, but at least know what you're getting into.

Comment: @user151413: *Then again, the offer and acceptance is considered formal* Is **considered** formal, or **is** formal? I am surprised if you would not get a binding engagement fromù the company before resigning at the current one.

Comment: @WoJ What I typically know for PhD and postdoc offers is an oral or email offer, which both sides consider formal, but it is not legally formal. (I've seen similar things in the US where I signed my contract on the first day, though of course visa issued required some formalities beforehand.) If you wanted, you could get a contract beforehand, though it is not that common in my experience. Note that typically postdocs don't resign somewhere - their old contract just expires.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

This means one of two things:

1. The PI has a certain set of needs right now and wants them met. Your needs are irrelevant. This will be the case for the duration of your employment - they'll be a decent boss until they need something and then that thing will be more important than anything you've got going on. This is a reasonably common PI mindset and most of them will respond to pushback - if you're assertive and can manage their expectations and needs this could be an ok fit for you.
2. The PI is cynically abusive to staff. This is a test. They want anyone assertive to get filtered out at this stage, because you'd just quit later in the face of abuse anyway. This is a shibboleth to identify postdocs who can be used and discarded. There is no way to make this job work for you. This PI is rarer but tends to be hiring a lot (for obvious reasons) and so you'll see them more than you would expect on the job market.

It's better to not work for either kind of PI if you can avoid it.

Comment: What if the PI is just really busy and knows this guy is shopping around and he wants the interviewee to decide ASAP so he can move on to his second choice? You might be right, but I know lots of busy people who got stuff that needs to be done and are looking to hire right away.

Comment: What if the PI has a set of needs which are prioritized over the needs of someone else? Isn't that just #1?

Comment: @Libor You mean it is a red flag that PI has other priorities than a random person who once interviewed for a job? You are way overgeneralizing this, saying that if a PD candidate's need is not the sole priority of a PI, then "your needs are irrelevant" when you are employed? First of all, a job candidate is different from someone who is a committed colleague. Also, can you imagine any situation, when a PI has a deadline to hire someone or when he has a serious concern that if he waits 1 week, no further candidate will wait for him if OP rejects him?

Comment: It's not a random person, it's someone you want to work with with for years or you wouldn't hire them. You're still just describing #1 with a weird unrealistic hypothetical.

Comment: @Behacad If the PI has a list of candidates, but is going to grab the first one who looks OK instead of carrying out due-diligence by interviewing them and finding the most suitable, that in itself is a red flag that the PI is incompetent on many levels.

Comment: Why is your red plane not appearing in your answer?

Comment: @user21820: the red plane caught fire and crashed earlier, burning itself, its occupants, and the red banner it was towing, and leaving behind the aforementioned smoking crater which was also red.

Comment: @Greg "Can you image any situation, when a PI has a deadline..." yes, absolutely. And in that case I would hope that the PI would tell OP about it just as OP told about his second interview. "if he waits 1 week, no further candidate will wait" no, I cannot imagine this. At postdoc level, waiting 1 week is nothing.

Comment: @Sabine here, generally, if you want a grant to start later than the pre=agreed start date, then you have to go through the process of applying for an "extraordinary start-date slippage". You probably wouldn't do this for a week, but if them saying no meant you had to re-advertise, it could easy mean a 2 month delay.

Comment: @Sabine There is a huge difference between PI not communicating all her/his problems, constraints,  and " Your needs are irrelevant." / "PI is cynically abusive to staff."

Answer (score 74):

In negotiation theory, such a tactic is known as an [exploding offer](https://www.crawfordthomas.com/blog/exploding-offer-hurts-recruiting/), and its adverse effects are well-known: rushing people into hasty decisions and giving them the feeling that they're disposable can create distrust and a flawed work relationship. It also signals desperation, which will damage the PI's brand if the word gets around.

Such offers can happen, but they are definitely not the norm, and could be interpreted as a red flag. Proceed with caution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I mean it was discouraging enough for me that they wanted someone to basically lead the project and working on research problems that they're going to define.

Comment: @U.User That alone would not be a red flag for me (but possibly a mismatch of expectations). A post-doc is supposed to be the phase in which you grow to become an independent researcher, a quality you will need when you apply for faculty jobs. Defining and leading your own project is a good way to achieve that.

Comment: I understand. However in this case: they wanted me to lead research problems that THEY'RE going to define. My issue it not leadership, I have got an offer because my profile screamed leadership and autonomy. As I mentioned, they admired that I can develop a research plan, but weren't excited about the research problem itself.

Comment: @U.User Already a bit more special, but still not a red flag per se - apparently they have some interest in this topic, but not much own experience, and are looking for someone to drive that topic. Of course, if you don't care about the topic, there is a legitimate mismatch of expectations which might ultimately not lead to a good experience if you accepted the offer.

Comment: Agreed, I'd clarify to ensure they understood but never work for someone who'd force me into a situation like this.

Comment: Great answer. You might consider quoting some of the adverse effects from the source.

Comment: Related: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2008/11/26/exploding-offer-season/

Comment: @lighthousekeeper While it is true and an ideal world it should be like that (and there may be variations between fields), the vast majority of PD jobs are sponsored by grants and directly working under a PI where you do not own the project.

Answer (score 31):

I wanted to also provide a different perspective, which adds to [Ian Sudbery](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/162884/4249)'s answer.

I was recently in the interview panel for a postdoc position. The first two candidates both performed really well, and first choice was a close call, with another great candidate following. It is common in the UK to extend an informal offer to the 1st candidate within a day or two of the interview. The first candidate was offered a generous (too generous?) two-week deadline to respond. 15 days later, he responded in the negative. The second candidate was very surprised
when we got in touch 16 days after the interview... 3 days later he apologised saying that he unfortunately already accepted another offer.

Now, the funding for this particular position was time-limited: it expired on a fixed date, regardless of when the candidate started. Advertising for a position generally takes at least 5+ weeks: the position needs to be advertised for at least 2 weeks, and there needs to be at least 2 weeks between informing the shortlisted candidates and the interview date. A week or two are usually lost in between -- and often, new hires can only start in 1-3 months time, or even longer if they need to get a visa sorted.

Add to all of this that over the last year, due to covid, the Universities' budget is much tighter, individual research groups get less (or no) discretionary budget, there was even a hiring freeze in play for a few months.

I'll let you draw your own conclusions from this. 2 days certainly seems very insensitive to (you) the candidate. But if this *is* the second time the position is advertised in a similar situation to above, the PI likely has a fire burning under their chair as well.

On the more practical side, I would suggest:

- If you really do not think the position is a good fit for you, reject quickly.

  You have expressed many doubts. Also, as many answers point out, this kind of pressure at the offer stage might indicate negative things about the PI. Or the PI might be under a lot of legitimate stress to fill the position in this call, and is yet to learn how to handle it better. You need to decide what you think is more likely.
- If you think the position might be a good fit, tell the PI that you are happy to start the formal paperwork.

  Then go to the other interview. Under no circumstances cancel the other interview unless you have a signed contract -- and if it's just a video call anyway, just attend it. The paperwork will likely take a week or so -- and if you have a point of negotiation, like salary, it might take a few days longer.

  If you want to "be nice", accept the contract if everything seems in order, and reject the other offer quickly if it comes.

  If you want to prioritize your own interest, and don't care about leaving a slightly negative impression -- wait to see if you get an offer for a better position. And then reject the current offer ASAP. If this is before the paperwork was signed, great, just let them know that you accepted a better offer in the meantime. If this happens to be after the paperwork was signed...  well, let's just say that most PI's will understand that forcing somebody to stick to a contract for the duration of their notice period is just causing more delays and does not benefit anybody. Also, most PI's don't remember *that one guy they never worked* with a year later.

  Don't do this if the 2nd offer comes in much later. But, if you do this within a few days, it should still leave the PI plenty of time to contact their second choices. If they send the rejection e-mails to their backup choices that quickly, especially without a signed contract for you, they should improve their hiring process. (You decide which duration of "much later" and "few days" makes you comfortable)

Answer (score 30):

I think that the PI is pressing you improperly. I'd suggest replying that you need to have the details in writing before you can formally accept an offer. You can say that you are interested and "inclined to accept" but without making a definite decision prior to having the actual details.

This is likely to give you the time you need for the other interview. And if it isn't acceptable to the PI, then I'd worry whether everything is proper or not on their end.

Comment: The two days deadline is to a time-frame to accept or to start the formal procedure. This basically means that I am going to accept since I'm talking to the PI directly. I didn't want to use that strategy. I saw it like this "if I tell him that I confirmed my attendance to a second interview, he should understand that there was another committee that made a lot of efforts to prepare my interview, and that I can't just decline after confirming". But 2 days is too short for me.

Comment: Again, you can only accept or reject knowing all the details. You can be "interested", even at a high level. But no commitments without full disclosure.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. The PI here says that he will generate all the details (or send the formal letter) after I accept informally. This means that he might send reject letters to other candidates if I "accept" informally.

Comment: How he deals with his other candidates is his problem, not yours. I wouldn't think too much about the informal accept.

Comment: If they send rejection letters to other candidates based on an informal acceptance and without a signed contract from both sides, they should improve their hiring practices.

Comment: @U.User You just answered your own question here... "But 2 days is too short for me." Thank them for the opportunity, but move on. Make sure you let them know that you simply cannot define your next several years work in two working days.

Comment: That "he will generate all the details after ... I accept informally" is a HUGE red flag. You should not accept until you know *exactly* what you're getting into, and the PI should know this.

Comment: Asking for an informal decision to go ahead before generating a contract is completely normal in some places (like here in the UK). In fact we are not even allowed to ask HR to generate a contract until the candidate has given us a commitment. That's a completely different thing to the fact they want the answer in 2 days.

Comment: What's the harm in giving them a commitment? there's no legally binding contract here, there's no obligation to, say, take the job if you find the terms are shitty - should, ideally, you commit to not doing the other interview? Sure! Should, they, ideally, not push you to accept without a decent amount of time to think? Sure! I'd argue these cancel each other out - make the *informal* commitment, do the other interview, and if it is a much better job than this, accept.

Comment: @lupe, the harm is to your reputation and to your self esteem.

Comment: @Buffy, it's true - but I'd strongly argue that without a contract, you don't know enough about the role to make a commitment, apart to express your strong interest in the role. However, you do owe them a very speedy answer - I'd be tempted to contact the other role, and ask if it's possible to interview early - I know we've done this before for someone we really wanted

Answer (score 12):

Just to provide a somewhat different perspective to what has been discussed already, I'd say that what you have just described is very common (no comment on whether its morally suspect or practically counter-productive).

I was given a short time limit to accept both my PhD position and the one postdoc I had that was secured via a normal advertised position. While the same tactic wasn't quite used when I got my faculty position, they did want an informal commitment shortly after the offer, even if they accepted that it was conditional on successful negotiations of the conditions.

Generally the explanation given is that the recruiter wants to not keep others on the list hanging around too long. Of course, the other reason is to try and get you to take this one rather than bothering to interview at the other and therefore secure a superior worker for what might be a less good position for the worker.

Comment: The faculty position negotiation and outcome described here seems to have the correct nuance. And the last sentence of the post is critical to keep in mind.

Comment: When you say "short time", do you indeed mean 2 days, like in OP's case?

Comment: For the PhD and the postdoc, yes. I think in both cases I interviewed on Friday, and they wanted the answer by Monday morning. For the faculty position, it may have been more interview on monday, answer in principle by friday.

Comment: From friends and such outside academia, I would say this sort of thing is even more common there. 2 days may even be generous.

Comment: @BryanKrause Makes sense because the stakes are higher in academia. Hiring a PhD student or post-doc is a bigger commitment than hiring a run-off-the-mill service worker, so a sane PI will prioritize "hiring the best candidate" over "hiring some candidate fast".

Comment: I had a job when after the interview I got a call and had to "decide" (actually, it was more like confirming that I am interested) that I want the job on the spot. And then it took the university 2 months (!) to give to official offer. So I agree, 2 days is not ideal, but I can imagine it happens often, depending on the field.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper It very much depends on the situation, but I have seen many hirings when the process had to run in a very short time, because of regulations, constains of the availability of money, length of the administrative process, etc. Also, but they may be in a hurry because OP was the only acceptable candidate or the last of acceptable few ones. They have to re-start the whole hiring process if OP rejects the position, too (I have seen such situations). I do not defend these practices, I just highlight that they exist, and PI can be unintentionally too harsh on the deadline.

Comment: It might be country-dependent. I once got a postdoc offer from a university in the UK with a deadline of 2 days. I know the PI well and trust him, and according to him he had little influence over that part of the hiring process; it was handled by the uni HR department. That deadline seems to be standard for that uni and possibly all of UK. (I was able to extend the deadline one day, which was enough time to obtain an offer from my preferred university and decline the UK offer.)

Comment: Yes. The experiences I discuss above are from the UK.

Answer (score 3):

If the company desperately wants you, they will wait for you. (A university waited for me a full year after I just finished my grad school.) If you desperately want the company, you will accept promptly. You do not seem to be in that situation, rather a feely-touchy one. So your response should be of that kind too. I would tell them that I was honored to be considered for employment and that, for your final "yes" you would need to see the details of the offer. Upon seeing the details you can negotiate the parts that are not agreeable to you. In the meantime your second interview will happen and you will know whether it is worth waiting for the second company to possibly offer you the job, etc.

Answer (score -3):

You're thinking from your perspective, with information you have.

There might be another candidate available, as good as you, but you seemed (bit) more promising AND they want to fill position ASAP. 2 days is not much, but not 2 hours as well. If you came to interview, you should have been ready to accept it. If not, why waste yours and others time, especially if they clearly indicated before, that they'll think they'll give you an offer.

Imo, it's more of a "take it or leave it" offer. You (and a lot of people here) might think it's "insensitive" or "too quickly", but if you've been on the other side of the table, You'll get my point- either candidate wants to work with you or no. No one needs doubter, "window shoppers" or CV builders, who'll probably leave the very moment the better opportunity arises.

You can try stalling of course (by say, asking for written offer or saying you'd like to have another call and schedule something for 1 week later or ...), but don't think it'll change for you much, because apparently they either want you to accept or move on and you need to make that decision now, not in 2 weeks from now, when there will be second answer available.

Comment: An interview should be a 2-way process: you do not come to the interview ready to accept, as the interview conveys a lot of useful information about the PI/team/University that you can't see from the advertisement. It's not window shopping, it's a mature attitude when looking for a position.

Comment: Shoving a take it or leave it offer down someone's throat means they're much more likely to leave the second they get another opportunity. Letting them choose to work for you means they're less likely to jump ship. You seem to have this entirely backwards.